# Grails: detemine number of calls to vaious API Services

Tags: grails

I have this working grails app, and i want to determine how many calls various parts of it's API gets per time unit.
This app offers 100+ web services, and 10k+ open connections at any time, so it is pretty busy.
It's written in grails 1.3.6 (developed over 10 years).

My overall target is to gain knowledge about which interfaces are actually used and how often.

I see several poor possibilities:

1. Log everything, parse the logs and 'grep -c'.... (Bad idea)
2. tcpdump... (Bad idea)
3. Increment global variables (thread safe) where i want to instrument it (least bad idea)

How do i get grails to tell me which services are called and how often?
...without killing performance?

Any ideas/pointers will be appreciated :-)

Comment: "10k+ open connections at any time" - Do you mean 10k+ open http connections?

Comment: Not all connections are http, some are on other ports/services inside this app.

Comment: That is a ridiculously high number of ports/services to be open in an app.

Comment: if you have 10K embedded devices connected it is not all that weird **;-)**

Comment: Which protocols other than http/https are those devices connecting over?

Comment: Many devices communicate by means of a proprietary protocol - i do not see how this is relevant though (but curiosity is welcome) :-)

Comment: It may be relevant because with such high volume you might consider counting mechanisms outside of the app and what form that traffic comes in would be relevant to sorting out how to accomplish what you are asking about. I realize the question is "How do i get grails to tell me which services are called and how often?" - But Grails might not be the best thing to give you the answer.  Sorry I can't help.  Best of luck.